Ngrok link is invalid
I am new to NGROK, although I have used it before... successfully. I have a remote data server and I am using NGROK as an IP tunnel so I can access the data over the internet. The data server port is 8080 (just for test). I start NGROK with the command line ngrok http 8080 and I get the following screen;
ngrok                 (Ctrl+C to quit)                                                                                                                        
Policy Management Examples http://ngrok.com/apigwexamples                                                                                                                                                                                       
Session Status                online
Account                       mhelxp.net@gmail.com (Plan: Free)
Version                       3.14.1 
Region                        Asia Pacific (ap)
Latency                       63ms 
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040 
Forwarding                    https://16a3-175-176-95-28.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:8080 

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90 
                               0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 

As you can see everything looks normal, but when I call up the link (https://16a3-175-176-95-28.ngrok-free.app) it says that it can't find it.
I've looked at the documentation and verified that there are no known issues but I'm stuck and I need some suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

start your ngrok session using ngrok http http://localhost:8080 as mentioned in documentation

I actually tried that. In addition to that (just for kicks and giggles) I tried entering the IP address of the data server instead of 'localhost'. Neither of those worked. I have a feeling that when I do find out what the issue is, I will feel really stupid. Right now, I'm will to feel stupid, just as long as I can get this thing to work.
